# Passing job id to next job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to build android app and then upload the artifact to another server by:

1. cURL a php page in that server by passing the job ID and artifact name after job completes
2. Consuming gitlab api to fetch the artifact's single file using the passed job ID and artifact name

So far, I have 2 stages `build` and `deploy`. So, once the build succeeds and the artifacts is uploaded, the deploy job starts which should be able to pass in the `build` artifact's job ID (the artifact name is a global var) which will finally curl my php page to initiate the download. Here is my gitlab ci config:

```
stages:
  - buildRelease
  - deploy

variables:
    fileName: artifact-Name.apk


buildReleaseApp:
    variables:
        GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    before_script:
        - chmod +x ./gradlew 
        - echo $setUpBuildScript | base64 -d > buildRelease.sh
        - chmod +x prepareConfig.sh
    stage: buildRelease
    script:
        - sh buildRelease.sh
    only:
        - tags
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - app/build/outputs/apk/playstore/release/*.apk
    after_script:
        - mv app/build/outputs/apk/playstore/release/*.apk app/build/outputs/apk/playstore/release/${fileName}

deployReleaseApp:
    variables: 
    dependencies: 
        - buildReleaseApp
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - tags 
    script:
        - echo $pushScript | base64 -d > deploy.sh
        - sh deploy.sh
```

Everything works for me except the php receives deploy job's ID and when the php tried to download the `build` artifact, it throws 404.

Is there anyway to pass the `buildRelease` stage's job ID to `deploy` job?

Comment: Maybe you could just download the latest artifacts? https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts 
This is a static URL which will always point to the artifacts created by the most recent pipeline.

Comment: That would only solve the issue partially @PhilippLudwig. What if I was running a pipeline with older commit?

Comment: Then the latest artifact URL would still point to that, since the URL always points to the artifacts created by the most recent pipeline, as I stated above.

Comment: Seems a valid point - at least for now as for my requirement. Thanks :)

Comment: @PhilippLudwig it failed. Probably I over looked and it seems like there is no way to authentication according to the docs to access a private repo pipeline?

Comment: It should be possible via an access token. See more here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/#personal-access-tokens

Answer (score 8):

this can help...

```
 after_script:
    - echo "JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID" >> job.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: job.env
```

You can access this job.env in other stages and call $JOB_ID to fetch the concerned job ID and also status

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your answer? How would you use it in the next job?

Comment: You can reference the the JobID as a variable in the next job like so:
  
script:
    - echo $JOB_ID

Comment: This is elaborated here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67707362/dynamically-save-gitlab-variable-for-job-that-runs-only-for-one-pipeline