# Dynamically save GitLab variable for job that runs only for one pipeline

Tags: variables, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to automate a DefectDojo template for Maven projects.
I need to create a Product in DefectDojo instance and store the ID of the created product.

I've written a script for a job that is run ONLY ONE TIME (one pipeline when project is created, then its removed as it's useless).

Therefore, I cannot pass the ID I got to other stages using the `.env` artifact since the job is not run anymore.

In fact, I would like to dynamically assign PRODUCT_ID as a GitLab variable, using a job that is run once. Is this possible ?

Comment: PS: How and when are you using this variable? In a different pipeline or different project?

Answer (score 10):

You can still pass it to other jobs or you can use it as an artifact and pass it for later jobs or pipelines. You can also consider saving it as a project variable if you want.
You can pass environment variables from one job to another job in a later stage. These variables cannot be used as CI/CD variables to configure a pipeline, but they can be used in job scripts.

In the job script, save the variable as a `.env file`.
Save the .env file as an artifacts:reports:dotenv artifact.
Set a job in a later stage to receive the artifact by using the dependencies or the needs keywords.
The later job can then use the variable in scripts.
For example, with the dependencies keyword:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "$BUILD_VERSION"  # Output is: 'hello'
  dependencies:
    - build
```

For example, with the needs keyword:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "$BUILD_VERSION"  # Output is: 'hello'
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted. I know I can pass variables from one job to another, but imagine I have 2 pipelines (for the same project). The first has 4 jobs, while the 2nd only has 3 jobs. I want the 2nd pipeline to have the variable from a job of the first pipeline that doesn't exist in the 2nd one.
In other words, I want to save a variable from a pipeline that can be used in other pipelines for the same project.

Comment: This sounds like you would want to use a combination of `artifacts` and `cache`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this project:
https://gitlab.com/whitespots-public/pipelines

There are many tools already integrated + there is an alternative system to DefectDojo, which has more fictionality for vulnerability management and more reliable